# 16.10 Unable to locate package libqtwebkit

Tags: 16.10

I have been using Blink in Ubuntu 16.04 and upgraded to 16.10 today. Now Blink fails with the following error

```
root@mark-Inspiron-13-7359:~# blink
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/blink", line 30, in <module>
    from blink import Blink
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blink/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from blink.chatwindow import ChatWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blink/chatwindow.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebSettings, QWebView
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit
```

and

```
libqt5webkit5 is already the newest version (5.6.1+dfsg-4ubuntu1~2).
```

Comment: When exactly does the error occur?

Comment: On starting Blink. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it but same problem. The repo is still xenial.

Comment: Usually, you get the "Unable to locate package" error when you try to install a package that doesn't exist. Maybe Blink tries to install `libqtwebkit` automatically? That's a problem, because this package no longer exists in Yakkety. I don't know this software, so I can't comment further (maybe a link would help).

Comment: After I upgraded to 16.04 I tried to start Blink from the Desktop. It flashed for awhile then just stopped so I tried it in terminal and it gave this error. I have edited my question to include the full terminal output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pay attention that you have two different versions of Qt: Qt4 and Qt5.
You got error with python2.7 which uses Qt4, and unfortunately there is little to do anything about it as QtWebKit was removed from shipped Qt4 packages (As You noticed you have QtWebKit present with Qt5 on your system, but Qt4 program cant use it). It is up to software developers (in your case Blink) to port the code to Qt5 (or PyQt5 in your case). This is quite huge problem not only in Ubuntu 16.10 but also in Debian unstable, and a lot of Qt4 legacy programs fails do to this removal of QtWebKit from Qt4. Porting code base from Qt4 to Qt5 is not so hard. (It is quite simple in python Qt (pyqt) code base, but can be more complicated if parts of program is in C++).

**update:**

going to github page of [blink](https://github.com/AGProjects/blink-qt), I can see that they allready addresed the problem and moved to Qt5. So either You will have to wait that blink will be repacked with upstream version in Ubuntu (You could try to fill the bug report to get the attention and faster up the process), or you could try to install the program manually from the source code.

Comment: and BTW, in the future QtWebKit is going be removed also from the Qt5. Qt made something for replacement called QtWebEngine, so the programs should move in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is an import error in python. One will get this error if python QtWebKit modules are not installed. Doesn't matter if `libqtwebkit` is installed or not. You may try running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
```

to install corresponding python modules.

or for Qt4

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyside.qtwebkit
```

Comment: did you tried that in 16.10?

Comment: this doesn't do anything at least for QT4